# using cut and paste to swap column

Tags: linux, cut

I got a file like below, I want to swap the second column and the third column.

```
1425    Juan    14.25
4321    George    21.11
6781    Anna    16.77
1451    Ben    21.77
2277    Tuan    18.77
```

Here's the way I used, it works but it's written in two lines.

```
cut -f1,3 test1.txt > cat
cut -f2 test1.txt | paste cat -> result
```

Is there any way that I can write it in one line?

Comments: Cannot use AWK to do that, only cut and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just connect the commands with `;` or `&&`:

```
cut -f1,3 test1.txt > cat && cut -f2 test1.txt | paste cat -> result

cut -f1,3 test1.txt > cat ; cut -f2 test1.txt | paste cat -> result
```

Or, use a shell that supports process substitution:

```
paste <(cut -f1 test1.txt) <(cut -f3 test1.txt) <(cut -f2 test1.txt)
```